Write the force balance in the $x_1$ direction.
We denote the component in the direction of $j$ acting on the
surface element whose normal is in $i$ direction by $\sigma_{ij}$ ,
Cauchy's Theorem
Are $\sigma_{ij}$, defined on three mutually orthogonal surfaces in a chosen coordinate system, capable of describing stresses on any surface? In other words, can the stress components on any surface be expressed in terms of $\sigma_{ij}$? To answer this question let us consider a tetrahedron shown in Figure 1.4.2. Three sides are formed by orthogonal surface elements $dS_1 = BCO$, $dS_2 = ACO$, $dS_3 = ABO$ whose unit normals are $-\mathbf{e}_1$, $-\mathbf{e}_2$, $-\mathbf{e}_3$, respectively. The fourth side $dS = ABC$ is inclined with the unit normal $\mathbf{n} = (n_1, n_2, n_3)$ pointing in an arbitrary direction.
First, let's show that
$$
dS_1 = n_1 dS = \cos(\angle\mathbf{n} \mathbf{e}_1) dS
$$
$$
dS_2 = n_2 dS = \cos(\angle\mathbf{n} \mathbf{e}_2) dS
$$
$$
dS_3 = n_3 dS = \cos(\angle\mathbf{n} \mathbf{e}_3) dS
$$
In other words,
$$dS_i = n_i dS, \quad i = 1, 2, 3. $$

Consider an arbitrary constant vector $\mathbf{A}$. By Gauss' theorem,
$$
\int \int \int_V \nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} \ dV = \int \int_S \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{n} \ dS,
$$
where $V$ is the volume of the tetrahedron and $S$ the total surface of the tetrahedron. Since $\mathbf{A}$ is a constant vector, $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} = 0$.
$$
0 = \int \int_S \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{n} \ dS = \mathbf{A} \cdot \int  \int_S \mathbf{n}  dS = 0.
$$
Since $\mathbf{A}$ is arbitrary,
$$
\int \int_S \mathbf{n}  dS = 0 = \mathbf{n} dS - \mathbf{e}_1 dS_1 - \mathbf{e}_2 dS_2 - \mathbf{e}_3 dS_3.
$$
Hence,
$$
\mathbf{n} \cdot \mathbf{e}_1 dS = n_1 dS = dS_1 
$$
$$
\mathbf{n} \cdot \mathbf{e}_2 dS = n_2 dS = dS_2 
$$
$$
\mathbf{n} \cdot \mathbf{e}_3 dS = n_3 dS = dS_3 
$$
Note that the volume of the tetrahedron is $\frac{1}{3} h dS$ where $h$ is the vertical distance from the origin to the surface $dS$.
Next, we consider the force balance in the $x_1$ direction, i.e., $F_x = ma_x$:
$$-\sigma_{11} n_1 dS - \sigma_{21} n_2 dS - \sigma_{31} n_3 dS + \Sigma_1 dS + \rho f_x \frac{h}{3} dS = \rho \frac{h}{3} dS \frac{dq_1}{dt}.$$
where $f_x$ is the $x$ component of the body force per unit volume.
Question
Write the force balance in the $x_1$ direction.
My attempt
It is given in the text $$-\sigma_{11} n_1 dS - \sigma_{21} n_2 dS - \sigma_{31} n_3 dS + \Sigma_1 dS + \rho f_x \frac{h}{3} dS = \rho \frac{h}{3} dS \frac{dq_1}{dt}.$$
Consider the surface $dS_1$, I can see that stress in $x-$ direction is $\sigma_{11}$. Hence the Force in $x-$ direction is $\sigma_{11}S_1=\sigma_{11}dS_1=\sigma_{11}n_1dS_1$
Consider the surface $dS_2$, I can see that stress in $x-$ direction is $\sigma_{21}$. Hence the Force in $x-$ direction is $\sigma_{21}S_2=\sigma_{21}dS_2=\sigma_{21}n_2dS$
Consider the surface $dS_3$, I can see that stress in $x-$ direction is $\sigma_{31}$. Hence the Force in $x-$ direction is $\sigma_{31}S_3=\sigma_{31}dS_3=\sigma_{31}n_3dS$
Consider the surface $dS$, I can see that stress in $x-$ direction is $\Sigma_1$. Hence the Force in $x-$ direction is $\Sigma_1dS$
where $f_x$ is the $x$ component of the body force per unit volume. hence the Total body force in the $x-$ direction is $\rho f_x \frac{h}{3} dS$
Am I correct?
How do I give sign? How do I determine the direction? Please help me.
